# Creating Conditional Column in excel or power bi

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi

[image: excel_problem]

I have a problem which can be solved in either excel or power bi. From the image provided i want to create a new column so that the Program/Course will only contain the values Program and values containing Kurs will be in their own column. Is there a way to do that using either excel or Power BI.

Comment: Are you using Data Import or Direct Query?

Comment: I am using direct Query

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Query Editor to rename the current Program/Course column, then create 2 Conditional Columns to split the data the way you want e.g.

```
Program/Course = if [Program/Course - Original] <> "Kurs" then [Program/Course - Original] else null

Course = if [Program/Course - Original] = "Kurs" then [Program/Course - Original] else null
```

Finally I would remove the renamed column.